# python attribute error?

Tags: python, attributes

I'm working on a simple python game in which the player attempts to guess letters contained in a word. The problem is, when I print a word, it's printing the \n at the end.

It looks like I need to use .strip to remove it. However, when I use it as seen in the following code, I get an attribute error saying that the list object has no attribute "strip".

Sorry for the newbie question.

```
import random
with open('wordlist.txt') as wordList:
    secretWord = random.sample(wordList.readlines(), 1).strip()

print (secretWord)
```

Comment: Seeing as you've [solved this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775920/letter-guessing-game-in-python), it would be nice if you Accepted the answer here that helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's because lists don't have an attribute named `strip`. If you try `print secretWord` you'll notice that it's a `list` (of length 1), not a `string`. You need to access the string contained in that list, rather than the list itself.

```
secretWord = random.sample(wordList.readlines(), 1)[0].strip()
```

Of course, this would be much easier/cleaner if you used `choice` instead of `sample`, since you're only grabbing one word:

```
secretWord = random.choice(wordList.readlines()).strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Right. Strings in Python are not lists -- you have to convert between the two (though they often behave similarly).

If you'd like to turn a list of string into a string, you can join on the empty string:

```
x = ''.join(list_of_strings)
```

`x` is now a string. You'll have to do something similar to get from what you got out of `random.sample` (a list) to a string.

Answer (score 0):

print adds a newline. You need to use something lower level, like [os.write](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.write)

Comment: This isn't the problem he's having; he's seeing the `'\n'` because `secretWord` is a list instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

[`random.sample()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) will return a list, it looks like you are trying to randomly select a single element from the list so you should use [`random.choice()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) instead:

```
import random
with open('wordlist.txt') as wordList:
    secretWord = random.choice(wordList.readlines()).strip()

print (secretWord)
```